# Workspace switching not working

Tags: unity, launcher, workspaces

Ubuntu 16.04 all up to date and upgraded, Acer i5, 6-GB, 250GB-SSD

I suspect something has changed in a recent Update or Upgrade.

I cannot change workspaces by clicking on the Launcher icon. Also when I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in any workspace it only shows the current program running in that workspace and a clear desktop as the only two options-- even if all four workspaces have programs running them.

The **only** way (hot-keys be damned) is to use the divided workspace icon and then select the workspace I want. None of the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+keys or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> etc work anymore.

How can I get this back to the way it has been working for years?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I installed compiz and checked the Desktop-Wall and it is working again. No idea why I have had to install compiz, but it is working as it always has.

Brute force prevails. :)